# Trying to understand if this has an identity

Tags: abstract-algebra

I have a group defined as $ ( \mathbb{R}, * ) $ where $a * b = (a+b-ab)$ for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R} $

So I get an identity as $b=0$ but I can't seem to find an inverse. What do you guys think? Any inverse on this?

Comment: The inverse must be $a^{-1} = \frac{a}{a-1}$, but this fails for $a = 1$. So this is not a group operation

Comment: How did you find this inverse in the first place?

Comment: Just solve $0 = a * b = a + b - ab$

Comment: I see. Thank you. So there is no inverse and it is therefore only a semi group?

Comment: How would I check whether $ \frac {ab}{2} $ is associative? Sorry for asking another question in my thread, but if you would like to answer both you can put it in answer and I will accept it as best answer.

Comment: By $\frac{ab}{2}$ do you mean regular multiplication, or $\frac{a*b}{2}$ with $*$ as above?

Comment: Exactly like above except in $ \mathbb {Q} $

Comment: The answer I gave below works in both $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{Q}$. Does this answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the identity of $*$ must be $0$, the inverse must be given by $a^{-1} = \frac{a}{a-1}$. However, this fails for $1$, and indeed $1$ has no inverse under $*$, since $a * 1 = 1 \ne 0$ for every $a \in \mathbb{R}$.

You can check that the operation $*$ is associative: $a * (b * c) = a * (b + c - bc) = a + (b + c - bc) - a(b + c - bc)$, while $(a * b) * c = (a + b - ab) * c = (a + b - ab) + c - (a + b - ab)c$, and both are equal to $a + b + c - ab - ac - bc + abc$. Thus $(\mathbb{R}, *)$ is a monoid, but not a group.